# Is there any way to perform text extraction from image more accurately?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, tesseract, text-extraction

I am trying to extract text from an image, but with handwriting images, I am not able to get proper results. Also, I want to extract some Hindi Language text from images.

I have used tesseract library to extract text from an image. It works pretty well with digital texts but not works with handwritten texts.

Input image

[image: This is the image I am using.]

Output Image

[image: This is the result I am getting.]

```
def get_string(path):

    #read image with openCV
    img = cv2.imread(path)

    #convert image to grayscale
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Define config parameters.
    # '-l eng'  for using the English language
    # '--oem 1' for using LSTM OCR Engine
    config = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 3')

    #apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations = 1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations = 1)

    #write the image after performing preprocessing
    cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", img)

    #extracting text from image using tesseract
    cv2.imshow("threshold.png", img)
    cv2.waitKey(4000)
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("threshold.png"), config = config)

    #writing the extracted data to file
    f = open("sample.txt","w+")
    f.write(result) 
    f.close()
```

Comment: Where is your test image and result image?

Comment: Added the links to the test image and results.

Comment: I  can just tell you, there is no easy way to extract handwriting text. You maybe need to train DNN, on a lot of handwriting data. Because handwriting text does not have a regular shape and size, so it makes it hard to extract.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Any reference links from where I can get help from?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give you some useful reference, extracting handwriting text is not something an easy job, the only I can say is: you should for DNN, Deep Learning, and Neural Network if can help you, but this one needs a huge amount of data to train the model on.